# SQL sorting partial alphabetical order

Tags: java, sql

I am having a hard time with SQL. I am using this demo of SQL [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_tryit.asp)

but I cannot figure out how to list only companies that begin with A or F along with address and city. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the like operator which would use an index if present.

```
SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City
FROM customers
WHERE CompanyName like '[af]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City
FROM customers
WHERE lower(substring(CompanyName,0,1)) in ('a','f')
```

Comment: when I tried pasting this ito the "try now" all I got was a blank screen.

Comment: that website does not support these operands

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

```
where  lower(substring(title,0,1)) in ('a', 'f')
```